# expect_background affecting other expect's behavior

Tags: expect

I'm writting an expect script to automate some tests. To detect when a general error occurs (which can happen at any phase of the test), instead of repeating the same pattern (for instance, "Rebooting system") on each `expect` command, I decided to use `expect_background` for that kind of condition.

What I understand about the `expect_background` command is that it is checked against all input text before the currently active `expect`. So, if both `expect_background` and `expect` are waiting for the same pattern, I expect (with the pun, please ;-) ) both actions to be triggered. For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./counter.sh

expect_background {
  "5" { puts "expect-bg"; }
}

expect {
  "9" { puts "expect-9"; }
}

expect {
  "20" { puts "expect-20"; }
}
```

The `./counter.sh` script counts from 1 to 20 with intervals of 1 second. According to the behavior I described above, `"expect-bg"` should be printed at `5` and `15`, `expect-9` at `9`, and `"expect-20"` at `20`. But here is what I get:

```
$ ./expect_bg.expect  
spawn ./counter.sh
1
2
3
4
5
expect-bg
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
expect-bg
16
17
18
19
20
```

Why is that happening? And how to I get the behavior described?

Comment: According to the manual, doing an `expect` when an `expect_background` is unblocked does not work. (`expect_background {pattern {if 0 {expect_background is blocked, you can use [expect] here}};if 0 {expect_background is unblocked, don't use [expect]}`)

Comment: What does it mean an `expect_background` to be blocked/unblocked?

Comment: I suspect you want `expect_before` instead

Comment: @glennjackman: Not quite. If I'm in a sleep, for instance, and the pattern appears, it won't be matched with `expect_before`. I need something "full time".

Comment: either use `expect` or `expect_background`, not both. A blocked `expect_background` is afaik if a pattern matched and the corresponding script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I can produce your desired output with `expect_before` and `exp_continue`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sh counter.sh
expect_before {
    5 {puts "expect_before"; exp_continue}
}
expect {
    9 {puts "exp_9"}
}
expect {
    20 {puts "exp_20"}
}
```

```
$ expect counter.exp 
spawn sh counter.sh
1
2
3
4
5
expect_before
6
7
8
9
exp_9
10
11
12
13
14
15
expect_before
16
17
18
19
20
exp_20
```

When you have

```
expect_before {
    5 {puts "expect_before"; exp_continue}
}
expect {
    9 {puts "exp_9"}
}
```

you effectively have this:

```
expect {
    5 {puts "expect_before"; exp_continue}
    9 {puts "exp_9"}
}
```

If you omit the exp_continue, that expect statement ends with the first 5, so you never get a chance to look for 9.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion and it works for the given example. Unfortunately, for the real case it doesn't. imagine that, instead of printing `"exp_9"` the action for that `expect` command is to sleep for 10 seconds. For that little example your solution works because the monitored text fits in the 2000 bytes default buffer size, but for a real life log intensive application it doesn't.

Comment: Well, the sleep situation could be worked around with an expect + timeout but that's ugly and not 100% effective.